# NotInList event within a "jump to record" combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use an unbound combobox on a Customer form to navigate between records using the AfterUpdate event.
 
I have added NotInList logic to recognize a CustID that does not yet exist.
I can even use the NotInList even to run an insert into the underlying table to create that new CustID equal to `NewData`.
Setting `Response = acDataErrAdded` will even requery the combobox's rowsource so that new CustID is a member of the list.
However, the new CustID **is not yet in the form's recordset**, so AfterUpdate does not find the newly added record.
Clearly I need to requery the form, but doing this inside the NotInList event seems to fire a second NotInList event before the first NotInList has completed.
Has anyone worked out the timing of these events so that a new entry in a combo box will create a new record and then move to that record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `Response = acDataErrAdded` does exactly what I want automatically. I had preemptively put `Me.Requery` into the NotInList event, which was a Bad Idea.